# How to put a function in a function in matlab and plot it?

Tags: matlab

Now I am new to matlab, and now the basic syntax, however I am not sure how to write a function to loop for instance the following recurrence equation:

$y(n+1)=\exp(-y(n))$

..

where $y(1) = \exp(-y(0))$

and $y(0) = x$

Answer (score 1):

First define $x$:

```
x = 1;
```

Next, define the vector $y$:

```
n = 10;
y = zeros(n,1);
```

Initialize the vector:

```
y(1) = x;
```

Then build a loop:

```
for i = 2:n
    y(i) = exp(-y(i-1));
end
```

To plot:

```
plot(1:n,y)
```

Comment: Thank you! And if I would plit it? I would at plot(y(i))

Comment: @Gauss Type     plot((1:n),y)

Comment: Hm it gives an error when it hits y(0)

Comment: @Gauss I fixed it, the "for" needs to start at $i=2$.

Comment: It works¡ uhh however if I want to plot it I am getting dots instead of a line, any idea how to fix that,

Comment: @Gauss I just run the exact code I wrote and got a line. I don't know what could be going wrong..

Comment: Hm I have put the plot() in for, and getting three point while the vector has more point